# How to make form validation in Django dynamic?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to make a form that handles the checking of a domain: the form should fail based on a variable that was set earlier in another form.

Basically, when a user wants to create a new domain, this form should fail if the entered domain exists.

When a user wants to move a domain, this form should fail if the entered domain doesn't exist.

I've tried making it dynamic overload the `init`but couldn't see a way to get my passed variabele to the clean function.

I've read that this dynamic validation can be accomplished using a factory method, but maybe someone can help me on my way with this?

Here's a simplified version of the form so far:

```
#OrderFormStep1 presents the user with a choice: create or move domain

class OrderFormStep2(forms.Form):

    domain = forms.CharField() 
    extension = forms.CharField() 

    def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
       domain = cleaned_data.get("domain")
       extension = cleaned_data.get("extension")

       if domain and extension:

       code = whoislookup(domain+extension);

       #Raise error based on result from OrderFormStep1
       #raise forms.ValidationError('error, domain already exists')
     #raise forms.ValidationError('error, domain does not exist')

       return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the `__init__` is the way to go. In that method, you can simply set your value to an instance variable.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.myvalue = kwargs.pop('myvalue')
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now `self.myvalue` is available in any form method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a model that stores the domains? If so, you want to use a [ModelForm](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) and set unique=True on whichever field stores the actual domain in the model. As of Django 1.2, you can even do any additional validation inside the model, rather than the form.

Comment: No, there's no model behind it, relies purely on user input and a whois check(server request to third party). 

I could fix this outside the scope of the form easily, but it seems neater to be able to trigger errors from the form itself..

Comment: No, if you don't have a model, there's no need to introduce one just for this. Just a bad assumption on my part.